# Can't Reindex Data

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, reindex

Can't Reindex Data. Magento version is **1.7.0.2** When I try I get below error:

> Stock Status Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.

- Permission of `/var/` folder is 777 and permission of `/var/locks/` folder is 777
- Also I deleted all files from `/var/locks/`. This folder is empty

I don't have SSH acces. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove locks (`MAGENTO_ROOT/var/locks`)

Check the table `index_process`, for the indexer `cataloginventory_stock` set `status` to `pending`. Try to reindex data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pro-grammatically:

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    $index->reindexAll();
}
```